# Fetching using NSFetchedResultsController vs NSManagedObjectContext directly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I had faced a problem and could resolve it, but I am curious to find out what exactly was the reason.

I have a shared class which should give me leave / vacation information of an employee. I have a fetch request in my utility class which provides the information of leave to fetch the objects.

This part of the code is responsible for fetching leaves:

```
#define FETCH_DIRECTLY 1
-(NSArray*)targetHoursArrayOnDate:(NSDate*)inDate
{
#if FETCH_DIRECTLY
    NSFetchRequest *targetHoursFR = [CSUtilities fetchRequestForVacationOrLeave];
    CSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *arrayOfTargetHours = [[appDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:targetHoursFR
                                                      error:NULL];
#else
    NSArray *arrayOfTargetHours = [self.targetHoursFRC fetchedObjects];
#endif
    NSPredicate *checkDatePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
                                       {
                                           BOOL dateExists = NO;
                                           if ([evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[CSTargetHours class]])
                                           {
                                               CSTargetHours *aTargetHour = (CSTargetHours*)evaluatedObject;
                                               if ([aTargetHour.leaveDate isEqualToDate:inDate])
                                                   dateExists = YES;
                                           }
                                           return dateExists;
                                       }];

    NSArray *targetHoursOnQueriedDate = [arrayOfTargetHours filteredArrayUsingPredicate:checkDatePredicate];
    if (0==[targetHoursOnQueriedDate count])
        targetHoursOnQueriedDate = nil;
    return targetHoursOnQueriedDate;
}
```

Please note, FETCH_DIRECTLY is the scenario where my doubts are. If I use the FRC to fetch leaves, it fails. Whereas if I use the App delegate's managedObjectContext directly, it fetches objects successfully! This is puzzling me.

The way am creating my FRC is here:

```
@synthesize targetHoursFRC = targetHoursFRC_;
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)targetHoursFRC
{
    if (nil==targetHoursFRC_)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *targetHoursFR = [CSUtilities fetchRequestForVacationOrLeave];
        CSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        targetHoursFRC_ = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:targetHoursFR
                                                              managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                                                                sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                         cacheName:nil];
    }
    return targetHoursFRC_;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self.targetHoursFRC performFetch:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The only thing I am missing out here is, am not setting delegate to the FRC. But I dont need it since I am not interested in listening to the changes. Rather the leaves / vacation information should be ready when it is asked from some other module.

Is the internals of coredata somehow designed to inform FRC about the changes only if it has any delegates? Failing which, no matter when we trigger the -fetchedObjects call on FRC, it would give some old set of results?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set a delegate for the FRC, and implement at least one of the FRC delegate functions (e.g. `controllerDidChangeContent:`), then the FRC runs in the "no tracking mode".

That means that `fetchedObjects` will always return the result set of the initial `performFetch:` operation.

(See "Overview" section in the `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation).